# Draw vertical equidistant vertical lines on Trapezium shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

As the title suggests, I'm trying to draw vertical lines equally spaced on the `trapezium` shape. For some reason, the lines are not spaced out as expected. I am using the `calc` tikz library to compute the interline spacing. See the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    trapz/.style={draw, trapezium, trapezium angle=67.5,fill=white,
    minimum height=6mm,text width=2cm,align=center,inner sep=0pt}, 
}

\begin{figure} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

\node[trapz] (trapz1) at (0,0) {Trapezium};

%Draw inputs to trapz1 
\foreach \x/\y in {1/1,2/2,3/3} {
    \draw[->]   ($(trapz1.south west)!\y/4!(trapz1.south east) + (0,-7mm)$)  node[yshift=-3mm] {$a\x$} -- ($(trapz1.south west)!\y/4!(trapz1.south east)$); 
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}     

\end{document}
```

This is the output of the above code:

[image: Trapezium]

Not quite as expected. However, if I substitute the `trapezium` shape with the `rectangle` shape this appears to work correctly. I suspect the `south east` and `south west` anchors for the `trapezium` shape are not exactly what I think they are.

[image: Rectangle]

Which is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after the `bottom left corner` and `bottom right corner` anchors.

See the description of the `trapezium` shape in chapter 67.3 of the manual (for version 3.0.1a, dated 29 August 2015), there you'll find a diagram showing the location of all the anchors.

In the code below I also placed red dots at `south east` and `south west`, and simplified the code for drawing the arrows a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    trapz/.style={draw, trapezium, trapezium angle=67.5,fill=white,
    minimum height=6mm,text width=2cm,align=center,inner sep=0pt}, 
}

\begin{figure} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

\node[trapz] (trapz1) at (0,0) {Trapezium};

% highlight where south east and south west are
\fill [red] (trapz1.south west) circle[radius=3pt] (trapz1.south east) circle[radius=3pt];

\foreach [count=\x] \y in {1,2,3} {
    \draw[<-]   ($(trapz1.bottom left corner)!\y/4!(trapz1.bottom right corner)$) -- ++ (0,-7mm) node[below] {$a\x$} ; 
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}     

\end{document}
```